# Error in formula to neuralnet

Tags: r, parsing, neural-network, formula

This is actually a copy of a perfectly useful question whose answer was (partially) arrived at by the questioner. Original title: "Formulas with more than 512 characters for neuralnet model in R for text analysis". He eventually fixed the problem although the reasoning he gave was incorrect and he compounded that error by then deleting the question and making the comments and his solution invisible.

---

I am trying to fit a neural net model for classifying a website in one of 2 buckets. The training data features are the words in all of the links on the website, so for example, one website might have the features "home", "about", "contact", "products", etc. The data is structured as a dataframe with a class column, and then columns for each word in the training. Each row has the class (Qualified or Not Qualified) and 0's and 1's for each word that appears on that website.

The total list of words that show up a reasonable number of times is ~1000 and I would like to use all of them as features. However, there seems to be a 225 character limit on formulas, so I am not able to do so.

I don't have a good data set to give a reproducible output, but here is my code and the errors I am getting.

If I try to do a formula, it gets cut off:

```
nn.model <- neuralnet(paste("class ~ ", paste(clean.features, collapse = "+", sep = "")), data = training.data, 
                hidden = num.nodes)
                )
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : :2:0: unexpected end of input 1: ranty+recipes+contract+just+inventory+types+working+wine+hampshire+suppliers+rise+body+selection+laurel+trek+arlington+cabinet+citrus+advertisers+rhode+highway+intl+province+jewelers+cycles+wy
```

The same things happens if I use as.formula:

```
f <- as.formula(paste("class ~ ", paste(clean.features, collapse = "+", sep = "")))
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : :2:0: unexpected end of input 1: ranty+recipes+contract+just+inventory+types+working+wine+hampshire+suppliers+rise+body+selection+laurel+trek+arlington+cabinet+citrus+advertisers+rhode+highway+intl+province+jewelers+cycles+wy
```

If I try to use all the features in the data set, it says there is no "data" argument (even though there is):

```
nn.model <- neuralnet(class ~ . , data = training.data, 
                hidden = num.nodes, 0))
                )
Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Any ideas for work arounds?

Comment: Link to original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235474/formulas-with-more-than-512-characters-for-neuralnet-model-in-r-for-text-analysi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**

- **Problem:** `reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), "for", paste(sep="","X",1:5) ), quote(Y))`
- **Solution:** deparse(quote(`for`), backtick = TRUE)

**Details:**

After debugging the following line, I also agree with you that the error is related to evaluation of reserved key word in R language.

```
reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), "for", paste(sep="","X",1:5) ), quote(Y))
```

The actual error occurs when the text in `termtext` is parsed and evaluated by R

```
Browse[3]> termtext
# [1] "response ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+for+X1+X2+X3+X4+X5"

Browse[3]> n
debug: rval <- eval(parse(text = termtext, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]])

Browse[3]> n
# Error in parse(text = termtext, keep.source = FALSE) : 
#   <text>:1:30: unexpected '+'
# 1: response ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+for+
#                                  ^
```

To reproduce that error, I evaluated the `for` suffixed with `+` key words alone and I got program termination.

```
eval(parse(text = "for+", keep.source = FALSE))
# Error in parse(text = "for+", keep.source = FALSE) : 
#   <text>:1:4: unexpected '+'
# 1: for+
#       ^
```

**Complete debug trace:**

```
Browse[3]> n
debug: if (!is.character(termlabels) || !length(termlabels)) stop("'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one")
Browse[3]> n
debug: has.resp <- !is.null(response)
Browse[3]> n
debug: termtext <- paste(if (has.resp) "response", "~", paste(termlabels, 
                                                              collapse = "+"), collapse = "")
Browse[3]> ls()
# [1] "has.resp"   "intercept"  "response"   "termlabels"
Browse[3]> has.resp
# [1] TRUE
Browse[3]> intercept
# [1] TRUE
Browse[3]> response
# Y
Browse[3]> termlabels
# [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "for" "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5" 

Browse[3]> n
debug: if (!intercept) termtext <- paste(termtext, "- 1")
Browse[3]> termtext
# [1] "response ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+for+X1+X2+X3+X4+X5"

Browse[3]> n
debug: rval <- eval(parse(text = termtext, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]])

Browse[3]> n
# Error in parse(text = termtext, keep.source = FALSE) : 
#   <text>:1:30: unexpected '+'
# 1: response ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+for+
#                                  ^
```

**EDIT:**

**Solution:**
If computations like this are unavoidable, then one might identify the R language key words first and then use `deparse()` function around it, which will eliminate the evaluation of them as key words at that level, instead it will be evaluated into text.

```
reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), deparse("for"), paste(sep="","X",1:5) ), quote(Y))
# Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + "for" + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5
```

But this will produce error as `invalid model` during model creation. A better way is to quote the key words inside the `deparse()` function and then create a formula and apply a model with data.

```
reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), deparse(quote(`for`), backtick = TRUE), paste(sep="","X",1:5) ), quote(Y))

# Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + `for` + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5
```

Here is an example:

```
  df1 <- data.frame(`for` = 6:10, y = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(df1) <- c('for', 'y')
  df1
  #   for y
  # 1   6 1
  # 2   7 2
  # 3   8 3
  # 4   9 4
  # 5  10 5

  my_formula <- reformulate(deparse(quote(`for`), backtick = TRUE), 'y')
  my_formula
  # y ~ `for`

  lm(my_formula, data = df1)
  # Call:
  # lm(formula = my_formula, data = df1)
  # 
  # Coefficients:
  #   (Intercept)        `for`  
  #           -5            1
```

**`browser()` settings**

To change the global settings of browse on error, type in `options( error = browser )`, then debug your code and then change it back to factory default of NULL on error by setting `options( error = NULL )`.

In my above debugging process, I created a function `myfun` and inserted `browser()` command and then sourced it. Finally when I called the function, I got into browser mode. After completing the debugging process, one would remove the `browser()` command inserted into function code. **Note:** I did not change the factory default option of error on null to error on browser using `options()`.

```
myfun <- function() 
{
  browser()
  reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), "for", paste(sep="","X",1:5) ), quote(Y))
}

source( 'myfun.R' )
myfun()
```

For more info of commands (`c`, `s`, `n`, `Q`, etc) used inside browser, see `?browser`.

Comment: Insightful demonstration. Suggest you add in the needed code to change the factory default settings of options that allow the use of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest a possible starting point to isolate the problem. If it is a problem with the length of formulas per se, then it should be possible to duplicate the problem just with the creation of the formula itself. Try this:

```
form <- reformulate( clean.features, quote(class) )
```

Ew, just typing that makes my internal R parser cringe. Please rename your LHS variable to something other than such a central R function. Perhaps this:

```
names( training.data)[ names(training.data) %in% "class"] <- "myclass"
form <- reformulate( clean.features, quote(myclass) )
```

---

The questioner responded to other comments that I'm not repeating here. I had advised him that his theory of a character limit of 512 characters was not correct but he then posted:

> So with a lot of manual review, it looks like the word "for" happened to be exactly at the character limit that was mentioned in other posts (512). But the actual problem was that "for" was being recognized as a function in the formula. Sorry for all the confusion.

---

That's just not correct. The problem has nothing to do with a character limit in formulas but rather with the name of his column as "for". That is a reserved control function in R and would have occurred at any location in a formula. See this demonstration (showing some reserved words do it but not all)

```
f <- reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), "for", paste(sep="","X",1:5)), quote(Y))
Error in parse(text = termtext, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:30: unexpected '+'
1: response ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+for+
                                 ^
> f <- reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), "class", paste(sep="","X",1:5)), quote(Y))
# no error ... OK perhaps not a reserved word
> f <- reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), "in", paste(sep="","X",1:5)), quote(Y))
Error in parse(text = termtext, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:27: unexpected 'in'
1: response ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+in
                              ^
> f <- reformulate(c( paste(sep="","X",1:5), "TRUE", paste(sep="","X",1:5)), quote(Y))
#  no error, so maybe "TRUE" is not reserved and quote(TRUE) is?
```

So raising the question of whether a term can share a name with a function was correct. The answer was not exactly as I expected. If someone wants to deliver a more careful CS explanation, I would be happy to checkmark their efforts.

The other context in which this problem arises is with the prefix-`?` operator that calls up help pages. Try to get help with `?for`. You only get a line continuation `+` prompt. The parser is waiting for a left-parenthesis.